# How would I get a particular value from a JSON?

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get a particular value from a field within a JSON file. This is my first time working with a JSON file so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(API_URL + city +".json");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }

    bufferedReader.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This block would get the JSON from a weather website and then return the JSON as a string. This string would then be used below. Unfortunately whenever I run this app in Android Studio and go through the logs the logs constantly say that there was no value in `weather`.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    if(response == null) {
        response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.i("INFO", response);
    responseView.setText(response);

    // TODO: check this.exception
    // TODO: do something with the feed

    try {
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
        String weather = object.getString("weather");
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There is rain", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is grab information from the `weather` section

[Here](http://api.wunderground.com/api/0f137acb119eafe7/conditions/q/02148.json) is the JSON link I'm trying to parse from. This text box thought there were too many links in the JSON response for me to post it here. I'm trying to figure out what is going on and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response)`?

Comment: Yeah I just adjusted my code.
         JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                String date = object.getString("weather");

Same thing no value for weather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print out `response` to see if it is exactly your JSON or not.

Assume you get the JSON String correctly.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
String weather = object.getString("weather");
```

However, if the JSON your obtained is exactly your `response`, the above code do not work because there is not `weather` String. The root only contain `response` and `current_observation`.

If what you what to get is `weather` under `current_observation`, you should use the code below.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject current_obs = object.getJSONObject("current_observation");
String weather = current_obs.getString("weather"); // Clear
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JsonObject(responseString);
String weather = object.getString("weather");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample Weather app done using open weather map api. It has all you asked for.

Code here:
http://opensourceandroid.in/weather_forecast.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your response in string.
Now,start json parsing as per response.
OR
You can use Gson class as well for json parsing.

Get json value from JSONObject:

```
{"weather":"sunny"}
```

code snippet to parse the JSONObject.

```
JSONObject object = new JsonObject(response);
String weather= object.getString("weather");
```

Get json value from JSONArray:

```
[{"name":"name1","url":"url1"},{"name":"name2","url":"url2"},...]
```

code snippet to parse the JsonArray.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
    String url = jsonobject.getString("url");
}
```

Hope it'll help you.